# Will the upcoming addition of modules in c++ fix/alleviate the need for the pimpl idiom?

Tags: c++, pimpl-idiom, c++-modules

The pimpl idiom, as far as I can tell, hides a private implementation behind a forward declared symbol name so it can be declared and used in the private cpp module.

Example: https://cpppatterns.com/patterns/pimpl.html

As far as I can tell, because the class hosint the pimpl needs to know about its structure (size, aligment), the pimpl must be indirect through a pointer of some sort.

(or allocated as a block of sufficient size then moved/created into the location where it is reinterpreted by cast later.)

Does the upcoming modules specification solve this in any way?

Comment: I haven't read enough on modules yet but one thing I think I can tell for sure is pImpl is not going away in **libraries** that aim for a backward-compatible ABI. I would guess this makes it a language-agnostic problem, thus beyond any proposed C++ features.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[P0142R0](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0142r0.pdf)

> ## 5.2.3    Exported Class Properties
>
> An occasionally vexing rule of standard C++ is that of controls access, not visibil-
>   ity. E.g. a private member of a class is visible to, but not accessible to non-member
>   entities. In particular, any change to a private member of a class is likely to trigger
>   e-processing of any translation unit that depends on that class’s definition even if
>   the change does not affect the validity of dependent units.  It is tempting to solve
>   that problem with a module system.   However,  having two distinct sets of rules
>   (visibility and accessibility) for class members strikes us as undesirable and poten-
>   tially fertile source of confusion. Furthermore, we want to support mass-migration
>   of existing codes to modules without programmers having to worry about class
>   member name lookup rules:  if you understand those rules today, then you do not
>   have to learn new rules when you move to modules and you do not have to worry
>   about how the classes you consume are provided (via modules or non-modules).
>
> Rule 3
>   In general, any property of a class (e.g. completeness) that is computed in
>   the export declaration part of a module is made available to importing modules as
>   is.

As all properties of a class are visible to the importer, any change to those properties would be visible in the importer. I don't see modules solving the problem that PIMPL solves.

Answer (score 0):

You can replace pimpl with modules if you rewrite your public member functions as free functions. https://youtu.be/tjSuKOz5HK4?t=865